# Android video player too many request on server

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have download the video player example of Android Studio.

i have download the video player example of Android Studio.
I have replace default video url with my video url.

```
// Create the player instance.
    init {
        val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val audioAttributes = AudioAttributesCompat.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributesCompat.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributesCompat.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .build()
        audioFocusPlayer = AudioFocusWrapper(
                audioAttributes,
                audioManager,
                ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, DefaultTrackSelector())
                        .also { playerView.player = it }
        )
        info { "SimpleExoPlayer created" }
    }

    private fun buildMediaSource(): MediaSource {
        val uriList = mutableListOf<MediaSource>()
        mediaCatalog.forEach {
            uriList.add(createExtractorMediaSource(it.mediaUri!!))
        }
        return ConcatenatingMediaSource(*uriList.toTypedArray())
    }

    private fun createExtractorMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
        return ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
                DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "exoplayer-learning"))
                .createMediaSource(uri)
    }
```

When in run, i discovery that on server, for each video i have 3 requests.

Why?
Is it possible reduce to only a requests?

Thanks